Built-in keyboard not working after suspend on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I've got HP ProBook 4545s laptop, running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Everything is working except when the computer wakes from suspend, the keyboard no longer works. I'm guessing the Virtualbox left open before suspending could be the cause, but just a guess. I have to shutdown and power-up every time, so any help is appreciated. I cannot implement the suggestions to edit the GRUB file as virtual keyboard has no arrow buttons and nano editor does not support moving the cursor focus by doubleclicking. I've tried everything I can search online, but to no avail. Thanks
My processor: AMD® A4-4300m apu with radeon(tm) hd graphics × 2
Graphics card: AMD® Aruba

Suspend does not always work well. Whether it could be specifically connected to Virtualbox is something you could test. So test, then add the outcome of your testing to your question. Also include more technical information about your hardware. Problems with hibernation are for example quite common with nvidia graphics cards.

How to test the connection to Virtualbox?
I have updated the initial post with more technical information about my hardware.

You told "Virtualbox left open before suspending could be the cause". Then I think you could test by suspending several times, making sure VB is not left open. If the keyboard never freezes after that, then you can be pretty sure your assumption is right. No guessing needed on that point if you test a little for yourself.
